# Google Play Service dependencies on android scala project

Tags: android, scala, sbt

Is there any way to specify dependency for Android Play services on Scala SBT-Android project?
I need to write app that receive Google Cloud Message.

I tried

```
  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "com.actionbarsherlock" % "library" % "4.0.2" artifacts(Artifact("library", "apklib", "apklib")),
    "com.google.android.gms" % "play-services" % "3.2.65" artifacts(Artifact("play-services", "aar", "aar"))
  )
```

in Build.scala

But when I tried to build apk, SBT complains

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.google.android.gms#play-services;3.2.65: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last *:update for the full output.
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency:     com.google.android.gms#play-    services;3.2.65: not found
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What repository are the play-services found in?   It looks like you may not have that one configured to resolve from.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install with the Android SDK tool, the "Google Repository" and maybe also the "Android Support Repository", in case, you use the appcompat library.

Hre is my setting in build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies += aarlib("com.google.android.gms" % "play-services" % "4.+")
```

By the way, the android-sdk-plugin seems to be better maintained nowadays.